# Create gradle task for specific artifactory publication

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

This my artifactory gradle so far:

```
artifactory {
  contextUrl = 'http://artifactory.mine.com/artifactory'
  publish {
      repository {
        repoKey = 'libs-release-local'

        if (System.getenv()["CI"]) {
            username = System.getenv("artifactory_username")
            password = System.getenv("artifactory_password")
        } else {
            username = "${artifactory_username}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
      }
      defaults {
        publications('aarDebug', 'aarSnapshot')
        publishArtifacts = true

        properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'q.os': 'android', 'dev.team': 'core']
        publishPom = true
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see I have 2 publications: "aarDebug" and "aarSnapshot".
Is it possible to create two gradle tasks - one for each publication? Something like `artifactoryPublishDebug` and `artifactoryPublishSnapshot`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the benefit/goal of creating two different gradle tasks?

Comment: We have a core library which is used by many apps. If we create changes in this core lib, instead of a "real" version, we only want to deploy snapshot versions until all the other apps are adapted,. So our CI pipeline would need different tasks for all of these build types (snapshot / debug / release).